# wp7: in page Loaded event, bing map is null

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1

I just updated a 7.0 app to 7.1 and having an interesting issue with Bing Map control.

I am trying to reference the map control during the Page's Loaded event but the map control is null.

It is my understanding that by the time the Page's Loaded event occurs, all controls on the page should also have loaded.  I also call 'ApplyTemplate()' in the loaded event to ensure that templates have been loaded.

I know this description is kind've brief and I'd be glad to supply more details if they would help.

Comment: did you delete InitializeComponent() in the constructor? And the map control is created via XAML?

Comment: the constructor has InitializeComponent() and the map control is specified in the XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your page, you can't rely on the map having been loaded until the `Loaded` event of the map itself has been fired.

Comment: i was following microsoft's documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.95).aspx) where it says that the page Load event is not guaranteed to fire before all the child Load events fire.  However, they also say that if you include the ApplyTemplate() call, then your visual tree is guaranteed to exist.  so I include, the call but the map object is still null.

Comment: My point was that regardless of other events and the order that events are fired. The map will have loaded when it fires it'a Loaded event.